# Wordpress template hierarchy when subpages not defined

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

Example site(`mysite.com`) and page defined with wordpress as `mysite.com/mypage`

This page goes through template `page-mypage.php`. Now when I run `mysite.com/mypage/somechild` where `somechild` page is not defined with wordpress. This causes Not found error(404).

How do I make `mysite.com/mypage/*/*` go through template `page-mypage.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

wordpress is not slug base templating, please check

https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

assuming you have a page called mypage, it will use if exists

```
custom-template-you-define.php //if doesn't exist it will look for 
page-[slug].php // if doesn't exist it will look for 
page-[id].php // if doesn't exist it will look for 
page.php // if doesn't exist it will look for 
singular.php //if doesn't exist it will look for 
index.php //if doesn't exist White Screen
```

and if you create another page called somechild assign as child page, the same method applies to this page.

Answer (score 0):

You must select the same page template for child pages too. Make sure you have done that.

Comment: ok. There will be number of random childpages like `mypage/child-a` `mypage/child-abcx` How do I handle that ?